# Remove row if any column contains NA

Tags: r, dataframe, na, data-cleaning

I have a large dataframe. I want to remove the observation if *any column* contains `NA`.

For example,

```
     A   B    C
1    23  NA   2
2    NA  12   10
3    6   27   18
4    18  22   NA
```

the only observation remaining should be the third observation in the above dataframe.

How can I remove the observation if *any column* contains `NA`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
test <- data.frame(A = c(23, NA, 6, 18), 
           B = c(NA, 12, 27, 22), 
           C = c(2, 10, 18, NA))

na.omit(test)

 A  B  C
3 6 27 18
```

Comment: also include `na.exclude` and `tidyr::drop_na`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `complete.cases`

```
subset(test, complete.cases(test))
```

Comment: Yes or use `test[complete.cases(test), ]` (which is what `subset` does in this case).

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose way...

```
#Your df
x=matrix(c(23 ,NA,2,NA,12,10,6,27,18,18,22,NA),4,3,byrow = T)
x1=as.data.frame(x)

#actual solution
x2=rep(0,nrow(x1))
for (i in 1:nrow(x1)) x2[i]=!any(is.na(x1[i,]))
x1=x1[which(x2!=0),]
```